# Storybook Cannot find module '@storybook/angular'

Tags: angular, typescript, storybook, angular-storybook

I am trying to setup Storybook for Angular 8, however when running `npm run storybook` I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Button.stories.ts
ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Button.stories.ts(2,29):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular/types-6-0'.

ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Header.stories.ts
ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Header.stories.ts(1,32):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular'.

ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Header.stories.ts
ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Header.stories.ts(4,29):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular/types-6-0'.

ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Page.stories.ts
ERROR in /home/user/dev/storybook/src/stories/Page.stories.ts(1,45):
TS2307: Cannot find module '@storybook/angular'.
```

However, `@storybook/angular` is on `package.json` and it is installed, as well as the file itself does not prompt any errors when visualizing with vscode. I have tried to use all solutions from google, such as:

- Importing everything from `@storybook/angular` and not using `@storybook/angular/types-6-0`
- Adding `@storybook/angular/types-6-0` to `.storybook/typings.d.ts`
- Adding `../src/setupJest.ts` to the exclude array in `.storybook/tsconfig.json`
- Adding `"enableIvy": false` to `tsconfig.json` under `angularCompilerOptions`

[My package.json](https://pastebin.com/JBBGmPc3)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I used this guide https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/get-started/install to add storybook to an existing project and tried the very same fixe. Does anyone have an idea? I am using: typescript 3.7.5, angular 9.1.2 and storybook 6.3.6.

Comment: However, it is not a direct answer for this question, some might be interested. From my experience it is easily possible to add Storybook for Angular in an NX workspace with almost just one command as described here https://nx.dev/latest/angular/storybook/overview. I can highly recommend it if NX is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add the following line in "typings.d.ts" that can be found inside the .storybook directory

`declare module '@storybook/angular/demo'`